# problem in user location coordinate in mapview

Tags: iphone

I am trying to find the user location coordinate from following code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
    MKAnnotationView* newAnnotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotation1"];

    if (annotation == _mapView.userLocation)
        return nil;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D location3 = annotation.coordinate;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location4 = _mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
```

But it is always returning location coordinate as:

```
<-180.00000000, -180.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 3/25/11 4:41:29 PM India Standard Time
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

For the love of all that is good, don't get the user's location using `MKMapView`. Read up on [`CLLocationManager`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/) and cast the above abomination into the deepest `/dev/null` you can find.

P.S. Those values mean there is no valid location data.

Comment: but this method called after the mapview delegate

Comment: I am getting the same error : both lat and long values are -180.. How should I correct myself ?